# How To: Comprehensive Data Inventory

Tags: database

I recently moved from a developer position to a project manager position at a company in Atlanta, and my first big project is to perform a comprehensive data inventory on all of our databases and the applications that use them.

We've got about a hundred different custom applications written that span languages from VB6 to ASP to C# WPF. These applications work with one or more databases (in production, we've got about 150 live databases, many of them shared between applications) on one of about 40 different database/application servers. What I want to know is, for each database, which applications create/read/update/delete data.

Honestly, I feel pretty overwhelmed at the idea, and my questions for the community is: **How would you go about conducting this inventory?**

Comment: This may be more appropriate on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you don't already have an inventory of all the applications (the ones that matter, anyway) that exist in your environment, you can never be certain that you've captured all of them. For example, what about the auditing app that runs quarterly or annually? If it's not running while you're monitoring the databases, you'll never know that the application exists. When you disable its access somehow, what happens? If you do have that inventory, look at those apps & work back to the databases; any databases referenced by zero apps need to be looked into more closely.